# Update wordpress database table with multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to update one row of database with multiple where clause but its not working. here is my code...

```
$wpdb->update( 
'wp_cf_form_entry_values', 
array( 
    'value' => 'example',   // string       
), 
array( 'entry_id' => '$entryid' AND 'slug' => 'code' ), 
array( 
    '%s',   // value1       
), 
array( '%d', '%s' ) 
);
```

Comment: can you be more clear about what is not working? any error message?

Comment: This query is not working. I have read codex and found this way. But in that codex there was only one `where` clause, But i have put two `where` clause. So defiantly the syntax of using two `where` is wrong, may be thats why its not working. I have doubt on second last line(`array( '%d', '%s' ) `) and 6th line `array( 'entry_id' => '$entryid' AND 'slug' => 'code' ), `.

Comment: You have an error in second array. It's array and you cant use any others operator than coma between array row. Look hire into PHP documentation:
http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I got my solution earlier. SO now I am posting it for future viewers.
The problem was in 6th line.

> 6th line

```
array( 'entry_id' => '$entryid' AND 'slug' => 'code' ),
```

I make below changes in 6th line...

```
array( 'entry_id' => $entryid, 'slug' => 'registration'),
```

Now my whole update query with 2 where clause looks like below ..

```
$wpdb->update( 
 'wp_cf_form_entry_values', 
  array( 
    'value' => $regcode  //entering data in value field
  ), 
  array( 'entry_id' => $entryid, 'slug' => 'registration'), //two where  clause
array( 
    '%s'     //specifying which type of value entering in table
  ), 
array('%d', '%s' ) //specifying which type of value using in where cluase
```

);

I am also wonder even after two days why I didn't get the answer of a simple question from here. It was just a simple update query and no one knows or they didn't want to reply...